# javascript - Display string based on percentage / JSON file

Tags: javascript

I try to implement some sort of A/B to my website and I render the response from different JSON files. One gives me this kind of response:

```
     variants: [
         {"1": "test"}, 
         {"2": "test_test"}, 
         {"3": "test_test_test"}
     ],
     winner: "1"
```

Now what I try to achieve is, if a `winner` is set, I want to display it to x% of the users.
The logic would be like this:

```
     if (winner && winner !== "") {
         var len = variants.length; // 100%
         // display winner to 98% of users
         // and each other variant gets 1% visibility
     } else {
         // do sth.
     }
```

So we have a value of 100% (= length of all variants) and want to give each `non-winner` 1% visibility. The `winner` will get 100% - (1% * `non-winners.length`)  - something like this.

Is there a way to calculate this properly?

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: Is there a fixed length for variants array? If not, is there a maximum length, or a range, likewise?

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o no it is not fixed and unfortunately it could contain from only 1 up to - realistically - 10 different variants.

Comment: So you want to assign the first (100 - (length-1)) percentiles to the winner, the remaining percentiles to each non winner, toss a random number between 1 and 100 and display accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, you could use this to calculate the percentage value:

```
var visibilities = [];

for (var i = 0, len = variants.length; i < len; i++) {
  var visibility = {};

  for (var id in variants[i]) {
    if (winner == id) {
      visibility[id] = 1 - ((variants.length - 1) * 0.01);
    }
    else {
      visibility[id] = .01;
    }
  }

  visibilities.push(visibility);
}
```

This saves the visibility in an extra array. Now you can just check for the visibility if you traverse through your variants. Hope I could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks, this helped out for further development.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about visibility, but you could use `opacity` for giving a value, accordign to the winner/other count.

```js
function setOpacity() {
    var other = document.getElementsByClassName('other');

    if (data.winner && data.winner !== "") {
        document.getElementById('winner').style.opacity = 1 - data.variants.length / 100;
        data.variants.forEach(function (_, i) {
            other[i].style.opacity = 0.01;
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('winner').style.opacity = 0.01;
        data.variants.every(function (_, i, a) {
            other[i].style.opacity = 0.99 / a.length;
            return other[i + 1];
        });
    }
}

var data = { variants: [{ 1: "test"}, { 2: "test_test"}, { 3: "test_test_test"}], winner: "1" };

setOpacity();
setTimeout(function () {
    data.winner = '';
    setOpacity();
}, 2000);
```

```css
#winner { background-color: #bb0000; opacity: 0; }
.other { background-color: #bb0000; opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<p id="winner">winner</p>
<p class="other">other</p>
<p class="other">other</p>
<p class="other">other</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant, but: what if data.variants.length is 100? :)

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o, then you need some sanity checks, because the opacity goes negative. anyway, maybe OP is enlighten us.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This already helps out.

But let's say I have three options and one winner, than the winner will have the value of 98% and the other two remaining will each have 1%.

And now I'd like to display the winner with a probability of 98% on pageload and the other two with a probability of 1% on pageload. So basically when the user enters my site, he will most like (with a probability of 98%) get the title with the value of the winner.

Comment: i have no idea, what you are trying to achieve.